# JSON Schema if/else with optional property

Tags: jsonschema

My schema has an optional `boolean` property named prepaid.  There are also three optional number properties.  If the prepaid property is provided and the value is `true` then I want the other three properties to be required.  It's working fine if I explicitly include the prepaid in the JSON, but if I leave it out entire, then the other three are still being required.  This is my schema.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.com/object1638395656.json",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "id",
      "name"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "uuid"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
      },
      "overageRate": {
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": 0
      },
      "pointsPerMonth": {
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": 0
      },
      "prepaid": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
    },
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "prepaid": {
          "const": true
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "required": [
        "pointsPerMonth",
        "monthlyRate",
        "overageRate"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, is there a way to say that if prepaid is either missing or set to false, that those three properties should not be allowed in the JSON at all?

Answer (score 0):

When "prepaid" is missing the subschema in the `if`, the result is still true: only when "prepaid" exists and it doesn't match the "const" will it be false. You need to add a "required" to the "if" clause to make it evaluate as false:

```
    "if": {
      "required": [ "prepaid" ],
      "properties": {
        "prepaid": {
          "const": true
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: If I do that then the validator says it's invalid because the required property `prepaid` is missing.

Comment: You misunderstand. Put the `required` inside the `if` block. It will not cause the entire document to fail validation -- it will only make the `if` clause evaluate to false,  And then you put your "things to happen when the if clause is false" part in an `else` clause.